# Javascript Autocomplete Script Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the following script to autocomplete data:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTags = [
        "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
        "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran",
        "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl",
        "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
      ];

      $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
</script>
```

I would need to use an array instead of manual entries assigned to the availableTags variable

I tried thisgs like the following but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTags = $result;

      $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is `$result` coming from?

Comment: Hi,$result is an array loaded in a different page trough an SQL query.
The array is visible from the current page as I have included it using PHP include.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use a php-variable (with an array) on javascript.
*Note: php-array != js-array*

Depending on your file structure you have 2 possibilities:

1.The javascript is included in your php-file

```
<?php 
    $result = array('foo' => 'bar');
?>
<script>
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
</script>
```

2.The javascript is seperated in another file (you have to use `ajax` here to retrieve the value of the php-variable):

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $result = array('foo' => 'bar');
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
     var availableTags;
     $.ajax({
         url: 'url/to/php/file.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
             availableTags= $.parseJSON(data);
         }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: The javascript is in the same page, I tried your first solution but it doesn't work.
Thank you

Comment: @ChrisA maybe you can show us more of your set-up (e.g. the php part). What is *doesn't work* meaning? Any erros? Is `$result` containing the correct values?

Comment: Hi,
Unfortunately there is no error message, the way I test it, is trying to type something in the autocomplete text box in the web page.
If I use static entries it works fine
I just tried to loop and echo $result in the same page to check if it contains values and it does

If I implement the follwing as per your suggestion, It doesn't autocomplete the values:

`<script>
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
</script>`

Thank you

Comment: can you show me the output of `echo json_encode($result);` ? Maybe it's in the wrong format

Comment: It looks like NULL

{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}

Comment: @ChrisA this definitly does not look like your static autocomplete data. Maybe your sql is returning the wrong data? Please consider to update your question with all the relevant information.

Comment: Hi,
I did some further testing and it seems there are 2 problems here
1: The $result is not returned as an array as I'm just saving the SQL in a variable, here is what I do in the code.php page:

$sql = "SELECT OS, RAM, CPU from Computers";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);

Comment: Second issue is that in the page where I want to display the autocomplete results, let's call it autocomplete.php, $result is not seen in the <script></script> tag

Indeed, regardless of the $result variable, If I define an array $test[] manually just outside that tag, I can't display it either:

Comment: <?php
        $test = array(1 => 'windows', 2 => 'linux');
    ?>

    <script>
        $(function() {
          var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;
          
          $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
          });
        });
    </script>

Comment: If I try to echo it from outside the tag it echoes the values correctly

 <?php
        $test = array(1 => 'windows', 2 => 'linux');
    ?>

    <script>
        $(function() {
          var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;
          
          $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
          });
        });
    </script>

<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118296/discussion-between-chrisa-and-empiric).